# Trying to get property 'email' of non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

***I am getting following error from my code written in Codeigniter when i enter a wrong E-mail.***

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property 'email' of non-object
>
> Filename: controllers/forms.php
>
> Line Number: 26
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   E:\Software\XAMPP\xampp\htdocs\ciauth\application\controllers\forms.php
>   Line: 26 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: E:\Software\XAMPP\xampp\htdocs\ciauth\index.php Line: 315
>   Function: require_once

***Below is the controller***

```
<?php 
class Forms extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function __construct()
    {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('user_model', 'auth');
    }

   public function forgot_pass()
    {
        if($this->input->post('forgot_pass'))
        {
            $email=$this->input->post('email');
            $this->load->model('user_model', 'auth');
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'E-mail', 'required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
            $que=$this->db->query("select password,email from users where email='$email'");         
            $row=$que->row();
            $user_email=$row->email;
            if((!strcmp($email, $user_email)))
            {
                $pass=$row->password;
                $to = $user_email;
                $subject = "Password";
                $txt = "Your password is $pass .";
                $headers = "From: user@testdomain.com" . "\r\n" . "CC: hamza_zon@outlook.com ";
                mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
                $this->load->view('user/header');
                $this->load->view('user/confirm');
                $this->load->view('user/footer');
                }
            else{
            $data['error']="Invalid Email ID !";
            }
        }
            else{
                $data['error']="Email ID is required !";
            }
    }
            $this->load->view('user/header');   
            $this->load->view('user/forgot_pass',@$data);
            $this->load->view('user/footer');   

   }
}
?>
```

Comment: So how do you handle the case where the email is not in the table? Your code assumes that the email exists.

Comment: how am i gonna do that?

Comment: Looks as though you are storing plain text passwords in the database - this is not a good idea!  Try and look at better ways of helping users who have forgotten their passwords rather than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check before `$user_email=$row->email;` that the as per your criteria record exist or not, if row is not exist then you will get that error

so you should check as below

```
$row=$que->row();
if($row) {

   $user_email=$row->email;
}
```

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: user_email

Filename: controllers/forms.php

Line Number: 29

Backtrace:

File: E:\Software\XAMPP\xampp\htdocs\ciauth\application\controllers\forms.php
Line: 29
Function: _error_handler

File: E:\Software\XAMPP\xampp\htdocs\ciauth\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: you need to put your all code which gonna execute after finding a record is in `if($row) {`...

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$que = $this->db->query("select password,email from users where email=".$email);

if(isset($row) && $row != ''){
  $txt = "Your password is" . $pass;
  //Coding...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply condition as, because in your case it may not getting the result from table for that email,

```
if (isset($row))
{
```

> **Note:** `row` method returns a single result row. If your query has more than one row, it returns only the first row. The result is
>   returned as an object. Here’s a usage example:

```
$que=$this->db->query("select password,email from users where email like '$email'");         

$row = $que->row();

if (isset($row))
{
    $user_email = $row->email;
    $user_password = $row->password;
}
```

Here is concise [doc](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html) for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle it like this,

```
$query = $this->db->query("select password,email from users where email=".$email);
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    $row = $query->row();
    $user_email = $row->email;
} else {
    $user_email = '';
}
//then your next if condition in which you are comparing two strings
```

Comment: A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'fffff' in 'where clause'

select password,email from users where email=fffff

Filename: E:/Software/XAMPP/xampp/htdocs/ciauth/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Answer (score 0):

$row=$que->row();

$row is probably being returned as NULL or a falsy value.

var_dump($row) to check.

```
if(!$row)
{
    die("user not found");
}
```

or

```
if(empty($row))
{
    die("user not found");
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it worked, instead of using "die", i wanna redirect user to same page and show the error

Comment: use php function header("location:page");